# Turn for loop over NumPy array into slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this for loop to calculate the elements of a 3D numpy array:

```
A = np.zeros((N - 2, N - 2, N - 2))
for i in range(1, N - 1):
    for j in range(1, N - 1):
        for k in range(1, N - 1):
            A[i - 1, j - 1, k - 1] = (B[i,j,k] * dy[j] * dz[k] + B[i,j-1,k] * dy[j-1] * dz[k]
                                        + B[i,j,k-1] * dy[j] * dz[k-1] + B[i,j-1,k-1] * dy[j-1] * dz[k-1]) / (4 * dx[i])
```

Where B is a shape (N, N, N) numpy array and dx, dy and dz are length N-1 numpy arrays. For large N this is really slow so I tried something like this:

```
A = (B[1:-1, 1:-1, 1:-1] * dy[1:] * dz[1:] + B[1:-1, :-2, 1:-1] * dy[:-1] * dz[1:]
                                        + B[1:-1, 1:-1, :-2] * dy[1:] * dz[:-1] + B[1:-1, :-2, :-2] * dy[:-1] * dz[:-1]) / (4 * dx[1:])
```

This does not work unless dx, dy and dz are constant. I also tried:

```
dX, dY, dZ = np.meshgrid(dx, dy, dz)
A = (B[1:-1, 1:-1, 1:-1] *  dY[1:, 1:, 1:] * dZ[1:, 1:, 1:] + B[1:-1, :-2, 1:-1] * dY[:-1, :-1, :-1] * dZ[1:, 1:, 1:]
                            + B[1:-1, 1:-1, :-2] * dY[1:, 1:, 1:] * dZ[:-1, :-1, :-1] + B[1:-1, :-2, :-2] * dY[:-1, :-1, :-1] * dZ[:-1, :-1, :-1]) / (4 * dX[:-1, :-1, :-1])
```

But this also does not work.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Can you post some example data in a quickly reproducible example?

Comment: The actual data is a bit complicated. But any B, dx, dy and dz of the correct shapes should work. I can't easily give data through a comment because B already has N^3 elements.

Comment: Any example or added could should be added to the question via an edit.  Comments don't format things like that well.  But we don't want the real data; we want an example where `N` is small.  For example one such that `A` is atleast (2,2,2).  Also, instead of saying "does not work", show the error, and better yet, show some effort in understanding and correcting the error.

Comment: It should work for any data of the correct shapes like I said so the data I actually use should not matter or be needed to make it work. But if you really need specifics you can say N = 5, B = np.random.rand(N,N,N) and dx=dy=dz = [0.5857864376269049, 0.41421356237309515, 0.41421356237309515, 0.5857864376269049]. Also I can't show the error because there is no error the numbers are just wrong. I also showed you two seperate ways I tried to solve this, I don't know how you can say I did not put effort in trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A[i - 1, j - 1, k - 1] = (B[i,j,k] * dy[j] * dz[k] + B[i,j-1,k] * dy[j-1] * dz[k]
                                    + B[i,j,k-1] * dy[j] * dz[k-1] + B[i,j-1,k-1] * dy[j-1] * dz[k-1]) / (4 * dx[i])
```

lets change the iterations to (0,N-2)

```
A[i, j, k] = (B[i+1,j+1,k+1] * dy[j+1] * dz[k+1] + B[i+1,j,k+1] * dy[j] * dz[k+1]
                                    + B[i+1,j+1,k] * dy[j+1] * dz[k] + B[i+1,j,k] * dy[j] * dz[k]) / (4 * dx[i+1])
```

and tackle the 4 terms separately

```
B[1:,1:,1:]*dy[None,1:,None]*dz[None,None,1:]

B[1:,:-1,1:]*dy[None,:-1,None]*dz[None,None,1:]

etc
```

I wrote these without testing, so there might be errors, but hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you. I used B[1:-1,1:-1,1:-1]*dy[None,1:,None]*dz[None,None,1:] + ... and it works now. Saves a lot of time compared to 3 nested loops